# Why aren't my session's persisting after setting session.cookie_lifetime

Tags: php, session, session-cookies, session-timeout

I have this line, that I added a couple of days ago:

```
ini_set('session.cookie_lifetime',60*60*24*7);
```

and can confirm in phpinfo that it's set to 604800.

But in my /var/lib/php/session folder I have no files that are older than 25 minutes.

So something's pruning them out, against my wishes.  Any idea what?

Thanks